# Counting hash values in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an array of hashed in Ruby that looks like this:

```
domains = [
  { "country" => "Germany"},
  {"country" => "United Kingdom"},
  {"country" => "Hungary"},
  {"country" => "United States"},
  {"country" => "France"},
  {"country" => "Germany"},
  {"country" => "Slovakia"},
  {"country" => "Hungary"},
  {"country" => "United States"},
  {"country" => "Norway"},
  {"country" => "Germany"},
  {"country" => "United Kingdom"},
  {"country" => "Hungary"},
  {"country" => "United States"},
  {"country" => "Norway"}
]
```

From this array of hashes I want to create a new hash the looks something like this:

```
counted = {
  "Germany" => "3",
  "United Kingdom" => "United Kingdom",
  "Hungary" => "3",
  "United States" => "4",
  "France" => "1"
}
```

Is there an easy way to do this using Ruby 1.9?

Comment: this hash has colliding keys.

Comment: That hash won't look like you want it to. There can only be one entry with a given key in a hash, so you'll just have one entry (I think guaranteed to be `"country" => "Norway"`. Would you like an answer for an array?

Comment: Beside the problem with your source hash. Do you expect `"United Kingdom" => "United Kingdom"` or `"United Kingdom" => 2`?

Comment: "I have a hash in Ruby that looks like this..." No you don't!  :-)

Comment: Sorry I edited my question - it should have been an Array of Hashes!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about this?

```
counted = Hash.new(0)
domains.each { |h| counted[h["country"]] += 1 }
counted = Hash[counted.map {|k,v| [k,v.to_s] }]
```

Comment: Perfect! - You're a life saver. I spent ages trying to get this to work!! Thankyou!

Comment: What if, I have distinct key. For example  - This is my hash, hash = { a : 5, b : 2, c : 3, d : 5 } . And I want the result like this - value_count(hash, 2) => 1 and value_count(hash, 5) => 2 where value_count(hash, value) is my method.

Answer (score 6):

```
domains.each_with_object(Hash.new{|h,k|h[k]='0'}) do |h,res|
  res[h['country']].succ!
end
=> {"Germany"=>"3",
 "United Kingdom"=>"2",
 "Hungary"=>"3",
 "United States"=>"3",
 "France"=>"1",
 "Slovakia"=>"1",
 "Norway"=>"2"}
```

Comment: What happens when there are more than 9 instances of a country? :)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't expect that. :) I should have read the manual before commenting.

Comment: You're welcome, it's better to learn from examples than from manuals